# Sort data in template from list

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-class-based-views

I am getting the following output from my ListView:

```
[<Book: Sample Title>, <Chapter: Chapter 1>, <Chapter: Chapter 2>, <Author: John Doe>]
```

I want to be able to display this data in a table, but sort it based on `Book`, `Chapter`, and `Author`. Is there a way to group these separately using Django templates? For example, I want to be able to do `{{ Book.title }}` | `{{ Chapter.number }}`,  `{{ Chapter.number }}` | `{{ Author.name }}`)

**views.py:**

```
class SearchListView(ListView):
    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        query = self.request.GET.get('q', None)

        books = Book.objects.filter(name__icontains=query)
        chapters = Chapter.objects.filter(title__icontains=query)
        authors = Author.objects.filter(name__icontains=query)

        all_results = list(chain(books, chapters, authors))
        return all_results
```

Comment: Will there always be exactly one book?

Comment: @JohnGordon No, that's the issue

Comment: Then a flat list probably isn't the best way to arrange your data, because there's no easy way for the template to tell the types of the items (i.e. the second item in the list could be a second book, or a chapter of the first book.)  Perhaps you could go with a list of dictionaries?